# Autoclosing of brackets and quotes in Spyder IPython console?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

How do I configure the IPython console in Spyder to auto-close brackets/braces/parens and quotes?

Answer (score 5):

(*Spyder developer here*) There's no option to do this, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

[Click to see what to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyOmP.png)

Simply follow this:

Go to Tools > Preferences > Editor > Advanced settings and tick the "Automatic insertion of quotes" option and click apply.

It worked for me, hope it works for you too.

Comment: It works in Version 3.3.6 but I noticed there is a bug in version 3.2.6 where it's completely broken.

Comment: Can't find such option in advanced settings.

[Mine looks like this:](https://i.imgur.com/E0daRQ1.png)

Or maybe it is moved to **source code** tab. But that option only works for the Editor not on IPython console.

Answer (score 0):

Please select the check boxes at

Tools > Preferences > Editor > Advanced Settings

Comment: That's for the Editor, not for the IPython console, so your answer is incorrect.